# Javascript validation - Error message only flashes for a second

Tags: javascript, html, validation, error-handling

I have this simple HTML project that validates an empty text and radiobutton field. The error is being displayed if one of the fields are empty, but the error message only flashes on the screen for a second, before disappearing again. Why is this happening?

Here's my HTML code

```
<form id="food_form">
<p>
    <label>Your Name:
        <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name">
    </label>
    <span id="error_user_name" class="error"></span>
</p>
<p>
    Favorite Food?
    <span id="error_radiobutton" class="error"></span><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="pizza">Pizza</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="burger">Burger</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="spaghetti">Spaghetti</label><br>
</p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And then my Javascript code

```
<script>

document.getElementById("food_form").onsubmit = validateForm;

function validateForm() {

    var validName = validateTextBox("user_name", "error_user_name"),
        validRadiobutton = validateRadioButton();

}

function validateTextBox(fieldId, errorId) {
    var text = document.getElementById(fieldId).value,
        errorSpan = document.getElementById(errorId);

    if (text === "") {
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "* please input your name";
    }


}

function validateRadioButton() {

    var radiobutton = document.getElementById("food_form").radiobutton,
        errorSpan = document.getElementById("error_radiobutton"),
        isChecked = false,
        i;

    errorSpan.innerHTML = "";

    for (i = 0; i < radiobutton.length; i++) {

        if (radiobutton[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if (!isChecked) {
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "* You must pick something.";

    }

}
```

Your response would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: on which browser it is happening?? did you checked on different browsers whether they are producing the same _result_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `validateForm` sets the error message but then you call `validateRadioButton()` which sets again `errorSpan.innerHTML = "";`. That is the reason of the "flash"

Answer (score 0):

You are validating the form, but you need to `return false` if validation fails on `submit` event. Try this

```
function validateForm() {

    var isTextBoxValid = validateTextBox("user_name", "error_user_name"),
        isRadioButtonValid = validateRadioButton();

    return isTextBoxValid || isRadioButtonValid;
}

function validateTextBox(fieldId, errorId) {
    var text = document.getElementById(fieldId).value,
        errorSpan = document.getElementById(errorId),
        isValid = true;

    if (text === "") {
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "* please input your name";
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}

function validateRadioButton() {

    var radiobutton = document.getElementById("food_form").radiobutton,
        errorSpan = document.getElementById("error_radiobutton"),
        isChecked = false, i,
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "";

    for (i = 0; i < radiobutton.length; i++) {

        if (radiobutton[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isChecked) {
        errorSpan.innerHTML = "* You must pick something.";
    }
    return isChecked;
}
```

In the above code we are returning `Boolean` value (`true` / `false`) for each of the functions and we are submitting the form if one of them is `true`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the submit button outside of the form element.

I've been having the same problem and this just worked for me.